# How can I upload individual CSV rows into different tables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I have a database with 5 tables around 5 records/rows in MySQL and I need to update it frequently. The problem is the file I upload will be csv file. Also I want each lines to go into 5 different tables.,I'm trying to updated `'where'` there is a unique id.

```
uid="001";
```

What is the best way to achieve this?
I've been trying since morning, and I only know how to update one table alone at a time. Your suggestions is most appreciated. Thanks.

sample of csv and individual table below

csv sample:

```
   id           |     name     |   title    |
   -----------------------------------------------------
   1            |     james    | Chief      |
   2            |     job      | officer    |
   3            |     bats     | lawyer     |
   4            |     Supes    | thief      |
   5            |      WW20    | Lobster    |
```

table1:

```
uid    |     name     |   title   |
-----------------------------------
001    |              |           |
002    |              |           |
003    |              |           |
```

table2, table3 and table4 contains the data and field as table one

I want james and his title to go to table1,
jobs and his title to table2,
bats and his title to table3,
e.t.c.
all on row 001

About the uniquenes, the 'UID' in the database (each of the table) is the primary key..... and i want it to import it and update the tables using the uid as the  location for each rows to enter the tables

Below is how i got the values in the csv, ignoring first line,which is the header alone.

```
$uid="001";
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {

        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 0;
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
             {
            
            $name= $filesop[0];
            $title= $filesop[1]; 
}

$sql = "UPDATE eyfstb SET name='$name',title='$title'WHERE uid='$uid'";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db,$sql);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

             $c = $c + 1;
            }

             if($sql){
            echo "sucess";
            } 
             else
             {
             echo "Sorry! Unable to impo.";
            }

        }
```

Comment: A different query for each line you read from the CSV would be my guess. But it's just a guess because there's so little context here - no sample of CSV data, no list of tables, no existing code attempt so we can get a better idea what you're trying to do. More info required please

Comment: the unique id is in the table

Comment: Why would you want to have separate, structurally identical tables? Also, please post an actual CSV (comma-separated-values) sample.

Comment: Because the contain different data for a particularr id, and storing  a delimited value is that bad ,my question gets closed anytime i upload it.

Comment: @biesorI want to use it to tell the query where to place the data ........update table..... WHERE uid='$uid'"

Comment: I can see that, but what is the point of using hardcoded `$uid` value? It had a sense if you had uid columns in CSV. but here I still cannot realize what for is this.

Comment: @biesior Oh,  it's the from the id in the URL . I used upset to get the uid from the url

Comment: And the whole Csv is for the uid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the best solution is the simplest one, so just creating five queries, you can even do it in the loop:

```php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8", "username", "password");

if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $row = 1;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($row == 1) {
            $row++;
            continue;
        }
        $row++;

        foreach (['table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5'] as $table) {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (name, title) VALUES (?,?)");
            $stmt->execute([$data[0], $data[1]]);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Or for UPDATE with uid replace the forech:

```php
foreach (['table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5'] as $table) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE $table SET name=?, title=? WHERE uid=?");
    $stmt->execute([$data[0], $data[1], $uid]);
}
```

Or even better with INSERT or UPDATE, note that in this case we're using named params.

```php
foreach (['table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5'] as $table) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (uid, name, title) 
        VALUES (:uid, :name, :title) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=:name, title=:title");
    $stmt->bindValue('uid', $uid);
    $stmt->bindValue('name', $data[0]);
    $stmt->bindValue('title', $data[1]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

SQL for `table1` .. `table5`

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
 uid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (uid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Note:** When you'll describe better how do you want to maintain uniqueness I'll probably add some other solutions. At the moment code doesn't know if James, chief from CSV is the same James, chief in DB.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218456/discussion-on-answer-by-biesior-how-can-i-upload-individual-csv-rows-into-differ).