# How can i split rows to update tables from a CSV file in php?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

How can update tables with separates OR different rows from a csv ?
i got here through a `specialnum` in url and get

csv format below:

```
   id           |     name     |   title    |
   -----------------------------------------------------
   1            |     jam      | Chief      |
   2            |     job      | officer    |
   3            |     bats     | lawyer     |
   4            |     winm     | thief      |
   5            |     WW20     | Lobster    |
```

i want to get individual rows separately into different tables...like
What i want now is for

```
jam and chief to be updated into excel1 table;
job and officer to be updated into excel2 table;
bats and lawyer to be updated into excel3 table;
winm and thief to be updated into excel4 table;
ww20 and lobster to be updated into excel5 table;
```

This is what i have tried through some helps here:

```
$specialnum="1";
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {

        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        
     if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
       $row = 0;
       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
           if ($row == 1) {
              $row++;
              continue;
          }
          $row++;

          foreach (['excel', 'excel2', 'excel3', 'excel4', 'excel5'] as $table) {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE $table SET name=?, title=? WHERE id=?");
            $stmt->execute([$data[0], $data[1], $specialnum]);
          }
         }
         fclose($handle);
      }

            
     if($stmt){
      echo "sucess";
     } 
     else
     {
       echo "Sorry! Unable to impo.";
     }

    }
```

each table has the same structure

SQL for `excel1` ... `excel5`

```
CREATE TABLE excel1 (
 uid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (uid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and each table already has a `uid` :1

Comment: How is this different from your question yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020487/how-can-i-upload-individual-csv-rows-into-different-tables-in-php-ignoring-uplo

Comment: @MarkusAO , I have tried the code, i'm still getting errors

Comment: Please update the question you posted yesterday with your results, following up with the volunteers who helped you there. When you update your post, it will re-surface, there's no need to make a new post duplicating basically the same question Thanks!

Comment: Okay thanks.. i will.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I upload individual CSV rows into different tables in PHP, ignoring uploaded ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020487/how-can-i-upload-individual-csv-rows-into-different-tables-in-php-ignoring-uplo)

Comment: nope, it doesn't....